# Is it possible that contract can pay the cpu/net for its users in the future?

Tags: eosio-code

Is it possible that contract can pay the cpu/net for its users in the future?

It will greatly reduce the gap between users and eos I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible but according to this post from Daniel Larimer it will be possible in the future.

[Developing Efficient Contracts](https://medium.com/@bytemaster/developing-efficient-contracts-8a8e62011c6d)